# How to resolve ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path

Tags: bash, python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Other such posts didn't solve my error.
I followed [this post](http://www.silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2012/7/24/Getting-Started-with-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-in-Python) to install **virtualenv** and **virtualenvwrapper** .
Now when try running mkvirtualenv Addon-Tests in my project's root directory, I get an error : **ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path**
I followed all other such questions but none of them solved it.

I had added this to my .bashrc file as instructed in that blog

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```